# facebook api for importing contacts

Tags: facebook, playframework

Hey anyone can please tell me, how to import contacts from my facebook account in play application.

And please tell me how can I get these values for my application

```
module.fbconnect=${play.path}/modules/fbconnect

# Facebook Connect
# ~~~~~
fbconnect.id=YOUR_APP_ID_HERE
fbconnect.apiKey=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE
fbconnect.secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET_HERE
fbconnect.model=models.User
fbconnect.landUrl=/
```

thanks,
I am looking forward for your help

Answer (score 1):

As I am sure you have read in the documentation of the fbconnect module, it does authentication via Facebook, but not much else.

What you could do is get the users Facebook user id in the `facebookOAuthCallback()` and then [retrieve the friends list manually](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). Play has a great library for accessing web sockets built-in; [you can find its documentation here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/libs#WebServiceclient) (I am assuming that you are using Play! 1, not 2, since you are using a version 1 plugin).

The other option is another Play module called [play-fbgraph](http://code.google.com/p/play-fbgraph/). It even has an [example page](http://code.google.com/p/play-fbgraph/wiki/Examples) with a call to get the friends list, which seems to be as easy as this (not tested):

```
JsonArray friends           = FbGraph.getConnection("me/friends");
```

Comment: Thanks Carsten!! but I am unable to do authentication via Facebook, as I dont know how to get my app_id or app_key, please help me with that

Comment: As Jean-Philippe Briend already pointed out, the documentation for dbconnect already tells you what you have to do: register you application with Facebook. Then you'll get an application ID, API key and secret key from them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation of this module :
http://www.playframework.org/modules/fbconnect-head/home

> **Prerequisites**
>
> Before you can use Facebook authentication, you have to register your application with Facebook. Be sure to note your Application ID, API Key, and Application Secret.

As stated by this module :

> Easily integrate Facebook based authentication into any Play framework application.

This module is meant to use Facebook authentication and that's all.
Nothing more.

You should consider use [play-fbgraph](http://code.google.com/p/play-fbgraph/) as stated by Carsten : it will allow to do much more things.